# How to assign a value to optional property of class

Tags: swift, class, properties, option-type, stepper

I've tried a bunch of different ways to assign a value to stepperValue to no avail. I get my Offence model filled through Firebase and I simply want to "assign" a stepper value to each offences so that I can make calculations i.e points X stepperValue .

Model swift file:

```
class Offence : Comparable {

var section: String
var name: String
var cost: Int
var points: Int
var stepperValue: Double?

init(section: String, name: String, cost: Int, points: Int) {
    self.section = section
    self.name = name
    self.cost = cost
    self.points = points
}

class Variables {

static var selectedOffencesArray: [Offence] = [Offence]()

}
```

This one is in its own TableViewCell class in its own swift file

```
@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {

 for offence in Variables.selectedOffencesArray {
        offence.stepperValue! = 3.0

    }
```

Comment: Solved below but it kept returning nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following just work

```
for offence in Variables.selectedOffencesArray {
    offence.stepperValue = 3.0 // << no force (!) needed
}
```